# Maps left top, not centered

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

When I'm clicking on add marker, the marker is in the top left of maps and not in the center.

I know that I'm working on V2, but I need it to work so I can get myself some time to figure V3 out.

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Already tried:
map.setCenter() on different places, but nothing works.

This is the main script:

```
<script
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=<?php echo $this->params->get('map_api_key');?>"

    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--



    var map;
    var marker;
    var markeradded=false;
    var markerfixed=false;
    var current_point;
    var catIcon;


    function initialize() 
    {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
      {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),{ size: new GSize(430, 315) });
        map.setUIToDefault();
         map.disableScrollWheelZoom();
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();   

    map.checkResize()


      }
    }

    window.addEvent('domready',function()

    {

        initialize();
        //var mapSlider = new Fx.Slide('gb_maplocator', {duration: 1000});
        var mapSlider = document.getElementById('gb_maplocator');
        //var mapSlider = $('gb_maplocator');

        <?php if( $this->data->published==0){?>
            mapSlider.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            mapSlider.style.height = '0px';
            mapSlider.style.overflow = 'hidden';   
        <?php } ?>


        $$('.gb_map_controls').addEvent('click',function(){
            if(this.getProperty('value')==1)
            {
                mapSlider.style.visibility = 'visible';   
                mapSlider.style.height = 'auto';


            }
            else if(this.getProperty('value')==0)
            {
                mapSlider.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                mapSlider.style.height = '0px';
                mapSlider.style.overflow = 'hidden';   
            }
        });

        $('btnAddtomap').addEvent('click',
            function(e) {           
                $('map_level').value=map.getZoom();         
                $('map_glat').value=current_point.lat();
                $('map_glng').value=current_point.lng();
        });



        GEvent.addListener(map, "zoomend",
            function(oldlevel,newlevel) {                   
                $('map_level').value=newlevel;
        });

        GEvent.addListener(map, "dragend",
            function() {                    
                current_point=map.getCenter();
        });

        <?php 
        if( $this->pin->map_image )
        {
        ?>
            catIcon = new GIcon();              
            catIcon.image = '<?php echo JUri::root().$this->pin->map_image.".".$this->pin->extension;?>';
            catIcon.shadow = '<?php echo JUri::root().$this->pin->shadow_image.".".$this->pin->extension;?>';           
            //catIcon.iconSize = new GSize(25.0, 32.0);
            //catIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(42.0, 32.0);
            catIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(12.0, 16.0);
            catIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(12.0, 16.0);
            map.disableScrollWheelZoom();


        <?php
        }
        if(abs($this->data->glat)==0&&abs($this->data->glng)==0)
          {
            $country=$mainframe->getUserState($option."countrytitle");
            $region=$mainframe->getUserState($option."regiontitle");

            $address= array();
            if($region!= JText::_('ALL') && !empty($region)){
                $address[]=$region;
            } 

            if($country!= JText::_('ALL') && !empty($country)){
                $address[]=$country;
            } 
            array_filter ($address);

            if(count($address)>0)
            {
            ?>
                showAddress('<?php echo implode(',',$address)?>');
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
            ?>          
                showAddress('<?php echo $this->params->get('map_default_address','Brisbane, Australia');?>');
            <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( ! $this->pin->map_image && $this->data->map_image )
            {
            ?>
                catIcon = new GIcon();
                catIcon.image = '<?php echo JUri::root().$this->data->map_image.".".$this->data->extension;?>';
                catIcon.shadow = '<?php echo JUri::root().$this->data->shadow_image.".".$this->data->extension;?>';
                //catIcon.iconSize = new GSize(25.0, 32.0);
                //catIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(42.0, 32.0);
                catIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(12.0, 16.0);
                catIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(12.0, 16.0);

            <?php }?>

            current_point=new GLatLng(<?php echo $this->data->glat;?>,<?php echo $this->data->glng;?>);
            map.setCenter(current_point,<?php echo $this->data->level;?>);
            marker = new GMarker(current_point,{icon:catIcon,draggable:true});

            GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend",
                function(latlng) {
                    current_point = latlng;
                    $('map_level').value=map.getZoom();
                    $('map_glat').value=latlng.lat();
                    $('map_glng').value=latlng.lng();

            });

            marker.disableDragging();
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            checkResize() 

            markeradded=true;
            markerfixed=true;
            $('addMarkerButton').disabled=true;
            $('addMarkerButton').setHTML("<?php echo JText::_('REMOVE_MARKER');?>");
            $('fixMarkerButton').setHTML("<?php echo JText::_('UNFIX_MARKER');?>");
            $('map_level').value=map.getZoom();         
            $('map_glat').value=current_point.lat();
            $('map_glng').value=current_point.lng();
            <?php if($this->data->published==0){?>

                mapSlider.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                mapSlider.style.height = "0px";
                mapSlider.style.overflow = 'hidden';   
        <?php }?>

            <?php 
        }
        ?>
        if(markeradded)
        {
            $('fixMarkerButton').disabled=false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('fixMarkerButton').disabled=true;
        }
    });

    window.addEvent('unload',function(){GUnload()});
    //-->
    </script>
<div class="gb_madata_publish">

<label><?php echo JText::_('Activeer Google Maps');?>:</label><div  class="gb_madata_publish_control"><?php echo $this->lists['status'];?></div>
</div>

<div class="gb_map_locator" id="gb_maplocator">
<a id="btnAddtomap"><?php echo JText::_('LOCATE_ADDRESS_TO_MAP');?></a>
<fieldset class="adminform"><input type="hidden" name="glat"
    id="map_glat" /> <input type="hidden" name="glng" id="map_glng" /> <input
    type="hidden" name="level" id="map_level" />

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 430px; height: 315px"><script>checkResize() </script></div>
<br />
<div class="mapbuttons"><a id="addMarkerButton"><?php echo JText::_('ADD_MARKER');?></a>
<a id="fixMarkerButton"><?php echo JText::_('FIX_MARKER');?></a></div>
</fieldset>


</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

And this is the JavaScript file that is included:

```
/**
 * Map controller buttons
 * 
 */

window.addEvent('domready', function() {

        var country_id  = '';
        var region_id   = '';       
        var address1    = '';
        var address2    = '';

                    $('btnAddtomap')
                            .addEvent(
                                    'click',
                                    function(e) {
                                        e = new Event(e);
                                        e.stop();
                                        if($('address1')== undefined && $('address2')== undefined) return false;
                                        if($('country_id')!= undefined) country_id= $('country_id').value;
                                        if($('region_id')!= undefined) region_id= $('region_id').value;
                                        if($('address1')!= undefined) address1= $('address1').value;
                                        if($('address2')!= undefined) address2= $('address2').value;

                                        url = 'index.php?option=com_listbingo&format=raw&task=addons.map.admin.loadadd&cid='
                                                + country_id
                                                + '&region_id='
                                                + region_id;
                                        url += '&street=' + address2
                                                + '&address='
                                                + address1;

                                        req = new Ajax(url, {
                                            onComplete :showAddress,
                                            method :'get',
                                            evalscript :true
                                        });

                                        req.request();
setCenter()
                                    });

                    $('addMarkerButton').addEvent(
                            'click',
                            function(e) {
                                e = new Event(e);
                                e.stop();

                                if (!markeradded) {



                                    marker = new GMarker(current_point, { icon:catIcon,
                                        draggable :true
                                    });

                                    $('map_level').value=map.getZoom();
                                    $('map_glat').value=(0);
                                    $('map_glng').value=(0);

                                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                                    marker.enableDragging();


                                }

                            });

                });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marker maps not showing correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761665/marker-maps-not-showing-correct)

Comment: That is correct, but last time people on this fantastic site make me cleare that this is not an forum, and when you have another question, or more examples ,that i have to make an new question. If i'm wrong i'm sorry... But, i still need help ;)

Comment: You should probably edit your original question to have all the code

Comment: i will do that, but can you help me with this question? Really stuck here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, i solved it by not using hidden divs.